# Is it possible to change the major from engineering to humanity (after master) for phd?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, major

I'm a M.A.Sc (equivalent with M.Sc.) student majoring in electrical and computer engineering at a top-tier Canadian university. My undergraduate studies were, reasonably, related to computer science and engineering. Robotics and implementation of human mental (cognitive) capabilities is my main research interest within these years. So, ***I had to learn a lot about cognitive processes of mind, biological aspects of nervous system and psychological concepts.*** Right now, I'm thinking about not to pursue technical majors towards Ph.D. and switch to psychology field. In no doubt, I have no classical background in psychology in view of previous degrees, but I have some fairly-strong reasons to justify my new idea to change the major:

- First of all, I was already interested in study of psychological affairs within the artificial intelligence (AI) framework, but now I'd changed my mind because I feel I am actually interested in **WHAT** natural aspect of psychology, not artificial **HOW** perspective. Furthermore, I think my contribution to psychology will be more gratifying (for myself) than AI, since the impact of the former will directly affect human-beings, whereas real imitations of AI are just like dreams, currently.
- (As I stated above) However I have no official preparation in psychology, my research experiences may show that I'm not an alien in this field. I have a couple of conference and journal papers, most of which are about implementation of cognitive processes into computer procedures. Hence, I am aware of them partly.
- My ideas are coherent enough to let me write a proposal to address what sort of contribution I've in mind to have. Obviously, that proposal will reflect a literature review that is by itself representative of my acquaintance with this field.

My target programs are well-known ones in US and EU, such as University of Cambridge. I've tracked some faculty members whose researches need background and mental preparation approximated by mine.

With all being said, my main concern here is whether aforesaid stuffs and justifications have any merit to help me get in such (at least in first sight!) irrelevant program compared to my background or it is impossible for me to hit this mark (I'll be carrying water in a sieve). In other words, how do universities typically analyze applications of fellows like me and what sort of credits are often important for them (which should be reflected into my application)? What are typical `admission committees' assessment criteria` in such situations?

PS. The probable answer might be:

> Just pursue another master degree (in psychology, this time), and then
>   apply for Ph.D.

Actually, I'm an international student and humanity funded positions (at least here) are very rare, typically granted to aboriginal candidates. So, please assume that pursuing another master is not pretty feasible for someone in my situation.

Comment: My guess is you can add a lot more value to society by improving AI than by doing whatever it is that psychology graduates do.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel: Thanks, but the question is not about finding a way to convince me that my decision is wrong! (As I made it after sufficient thinking about my future, goals and capabilities.)

Comment: That's why I put it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Cambridge [apparently](http://www.psychol.cam.ac.uk/grads/prosp-stu-pg/phd) welcome applicants with engineering or computer science degrees, so what's the problem?

Comment: @101010111100: Thanks to addressing. I mentioned Cambridge just as an example of well-known programs.

Comment: Given the financial considerations you mentioned, perhaps an interdisciplinary approach, with home base providing financial support, would be the practical way to proceed. // For less technical fields, it can be helpful to work on standardizing one's writing in English and improving one's writing skills in English, to ensure that readers will not have any trouble understanding your ideas.

Comment: @aparente001: I don't realize how your comment addresses the question. Could you explain?

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment.  It has two parts.  In the first part, I connect the financial dots.  I suggest that you consider choosing a home department where you can work as a TA, but with interdisciplinary studies.  In the second part, I provide a warning that a switch from a STEM field to a field like psychology is likely to involve higher expectations with regard to clear, standard writing in English. I believe it would be helpful for you to be aware of this. Such an awareness could help you make improving your writing in English a higher priority if you decide to study psychology.

Comment: @aparente001: What do you mean by standard writing?! If you think the question's composition is not flawless, you better stick to the applied mechanisms like `editing`. I've a cure for you: "Just open a text editor and press your fingers on buttons of keyboard, as much as you need". It may prohibit you from sending spams as either comments or answers, here.

Comment: I do not mean anything offensive or impolite.It is only advice intended to help you be successful in your studies. I can see that you are upset about what I said, but, as is often the case with your posts and comments, I cannot understand precisely what you are trying to convey.  Look, I only speak two languages well. There is a third in which I make a lot of mistakes, and there is a fourth which I totally butcher; I wouldn't venture to use it at all if I weren't trying to support my children bonding with their other parent's home culture. Not everyone writes flawlessly in all their languages.

Comment: I think it is pretty much dependent on the program you choose if they like you. As others pointed out technically it is possible - asking for general criterias for special situations like that might not be useful

Comment: I think @aparente001 was saying that the _style_ of writing in a humanities field may have different conventions and styles than a STEM field.

Comment: @mkennedy - That's true, but what I'm trying to say is that STEM fields tend to be more forgiving of language deficiencies than the humanities, which are more language intensive.  Since OP is asking a career guidance question, it would be doing him a disservice not to point this out.